# jQuery datetimepicker separator - setDate always sets today's date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, separator

Have a look at [this jQuery datetimepicker example](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#utility_examples) (go to the Examples tab, "Utilities" example).

If you try to run the following in your browser's console:

```
$('#utility_example_1').datetimepicker('setDate', new Date(0));
```

you'll see that the date is set to **today** (the time is set properly):

[image]

Actually, if you set it to a random date, the date is always set to today.

I tried to do the same with other examples on the page, and all worked fine. I think that `separator: ' @ '` is causing the issue.

Is that a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue was addressed recently in [the dev branch](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/commit/b0b8458e5763b85d83958c5dffb4bf9e1148dfe2).

I can confirm that all works fine with the latest `jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js` in the `dev` branch.